# Add element references to repeated items in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

So I have a list of objects in my viewModel that need access to each of their own individual elements. I tried using `element.ref`, but there was no element in the object.

**persons.js**

```
export class PersonsViewModel {

    persons = [{
        id: 0,
        name: 'Matt'
    }]

    // this function fails, person.el is undefined
    increase(person) {
        person.el.style.height = person.el.clientHeight + 10;
        person.el.style.width = person.el.clientWidth + 10;
    }
}
```

**persons.html**

```
<template>
    <div repeat.for="person of persons" element.ref="el">
        <div>${person.name}</div>
        <button click.delegate="increase(person)">+</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `element.ref` binding respects binding contexts just like all other bindings, and so the `element.ref` must reference the `person` object when attaching the element property.

```
<div repeat.for="person of persons" element.ref="person.el">
```